# Django asset pipeline

Tags: python, django, coffeescript, sass, assets

I am using `django-pipeline` to manage my static assets and to compile both my coffeescript and SCSS files. I am having trouble with the configuration of this Django app. What I want to achieve is for `django-pipeline` to read my coffeescript and SCSS files from the assets/ subdirectory and compile and compress them into the public/ subdirectory from which I have told Django to serve static files.

For reference, my Django file structure looks like this:

```
DjangoApp
    assets
        coffeescript
        scss
    bin
    configs
    db
    logs
    DjangoApp
    public
        css
        images
        js
    requirements
```

My current Django setting looks like that below (with unrelated stuff omitted for brevity):

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/public/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    PROJECT_PATH + '/public',
)

# Asset compilers.
PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.coffee.CoffeeScriptCompiler',
    'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler'
)

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'ie': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'scss/ie.scss',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/ie.min.css'
    },
    'print': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'scss/print.scss',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/print.min.css'
    },
    'screen': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'scss/screen.scss',
            'scss/screen-responsive-768px.scss',
            'scss/screen-responsive-992px.scss',
            'scss/screen-responsive-1200px.scss'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/screen.min.css'
    }
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'application': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'coffeescript/application.coffee',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/application.min.js',
    }
}
```

Perhaps this app cannot do what I want. Should I look for something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been playing with this for a while, with no luck. However I have found exactly what I wanted from `python gears` or `django-gears`. Considering what I wanted to achieve was to replicate Ruby `sprockets` this will be perfect.